# Connecting extjs with django rest framework api

Tags: django, extjs, django-rest-framework

So I have created the backend api with django rest framework. How do I connect my extjs frontend to it? I know how to communicate with the server and read/write to files on the server with Extjs and php, but I don't how to connect it to my django backend.

Comment: did you try [API Rest](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-classic/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.Rest) ?

Comment: I will try it out. 
One question. How does it know the url of the backend? Is url : '/users' really enough?

Comment: the short answer is yes

Comment: Must the django project and extjs project have the same root then? Or can I have a folder for extjs and then folder for api as long as they are on the same server?

Comment: you can set different folders and set the url as u like, also you can use the function buildUrl to change the url dynamically, but don't forget to use callParent function